# Easy way to generate identical Random Data

Tags: python, numpy, random

I have a reference data. I want to generate a model random data (RND). Can anyone suggest me in which direction i should look for so i can pose a much clear question. I understand this seems very broad question. But any suggestion will help me in searching much better and posing much better questions. Thanks

Real data format

```
Node Node time_diff
4443 2342 34
5424 4643 4
2352 4563 2355
2344 2356 43
2344 5653 5443
```

Nodes form pair and are connected for some time in seconds. I want to generate a random data with 5 instances from seed 0 to 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [random.seed()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.seed) with some constant argument, for example `random.seed(0)` before you start generating random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

you may have 4th col seed from 0 to 4. then, in 5th col use =randbetween(0,4) formula to generate random nos from 0 to 4. press F9 to have fresh random nos between 0 to 4 in col 5.

Comment: I have to generate the exact format of random numbers. Like Nodes and the time in seconds. If you to help me with some code ??